# Buildroot: annoying false error architecture for "/root/foo/bar.aocx" is "Advanced Micro Devices X86-64", should be "ARM"

Tags: opencl, buildroot, intel-fpga

I have a buildroot-based project, for an Intel FPGA SoC, using OpenCL. There are some precompiled OpenCL binaries for the FPGA in the overlay source directory with the file extension .aocx that should be copied to the resulting file system image.

However, those FPGA binaries are for some reasons recognizes as AMD X86-64 binaries and trigger an error when rebuilding the root file system.

Can I configure Buildroot to not check files with the .aocx extension?

Answer (score 2):

Files from a rootfs overlay are not directly checked, so I assume you mean that you are installing these files from a custom package instead? You can add them to the ignore list using the _BIN_ARCH_EXCLUDE variable. See the manual for details: https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#generic-package-reference